# Invoking a function for every 5 seconds in iOS

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer, delay

Is it possible to invoke a function in iOS for a certain time interval?

```
  {
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self  selector:@selector(serverConnect) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
  }
```

Is there an alternative to the above?

The server connect function is as follows:

```
  -(void)serverConnect{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@MYURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];

NSURLConnection *connection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(connection){

    NSLog(@"connected");
}else{
    //

}
```

It throws an error: -[TUTViewController serverConnect:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x907ef20

Comment: Thats pretty much the way to do it. Globalize the `NSTimer` and you can invalidate it elsewhere if you need to.

Comment: That's how you do a repeating timer, but it will run every 100th of a second.  Is that what you really want?

Comment: I have changed the time-interval and added the function that is being called.

Answer (score 2):

The error is indicating the issue. It shows 'serverConnect:' - the colon at the end signifies there's a parameter. Your serverConnect takes no parameter... hence the problem. It needs to look like:

```
- (void)serverConnect:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    ...
}
```

Comment: but i don't use that timer but just call the function. My idea was to connect to the server for every 5 seconds. Nothing much. Does it still apply?

Comment: The function has to take the parameter, whether you use it or not. The NSTimer docs can confirm this.